# Add observation at the end to an existing SAS dataset

Tags: sas

My dataset(named A) has columns : A  B  C. I want to add new observations (new row) at the end of it with the values: 1  2  3. There must be an easy way to do that?

Comment: Can you show the code that you attempted and how it did not do what you wanted?

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a duplicate, but as far as I can tell no-one has asked this exact question here before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `proc sql` and `insert` statement.

```
proc sql;
    insert into table_name (A,B,C) values (1,2,3);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 5 more ways of doing this:

```
/*Some dummy data*/

data have;
input A B C;
cards;
4 5 6
;
run;

data new_rows;
input A B C;
cards;
1 2 3
6 7 8
;
run;

/* Modifying in place - more efficient, increased risk of data loss */

proc sql;
    insert into have
    select * from new_rows;
quit;

proc append base = have data = new_rows;
run;

data have;
    modify have;
    set new_rows;
    output;
run;

/* Overwriting - less efficient, no harm if interrupted. */

data have;
    set have new_rows;
run;


data have;
    update have new_rows;
    /*N.B. assumes that A B C form a set of unique keys and that the datasets are sorted*/
    by A B C;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Comment: Please upvote rather than saying thanks - it's how this site works.